# Cannot push to heroku since latest Nokogiri gem update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

Everything seemed to be fine until Nokogiri gem update in Dec 27 2016, this is what it says in heroku logs and i can't seem to find out how to solve it. it works on development, it just doesn't push to heroku. Thank you in advance

```
    enter code here.
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.6
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Resolving dependencies...
       nokogiri-1.7.0 requires ruby version >= 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the
       current version, ruby 2.0.0p648
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Resolving dependencies...
       nokogiri-1.7.0 requires ruby version >= 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the
       current version, ruby 2.0.0p648
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: `nokogiri-1.7.0 requires ruby version >= 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the
       current version, ruby 2.0.0p648`

Comment: yea, i know that's the issue, but here's my problem, if i update ruby the app seems to break in other areas, so it's a lot more headache to deal with, and i don't have nokogiri in my gemfile, it's just a dependency in gemfile.lock. and i really don't know what to do to fix it

Comment: You could set a version restriction on nokogiri in your gemfile

Answer (score 2):

You can update your gemfile to a version that is compatible:
for example:

gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.9'